# Image sizing and serving

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

I have noticed that websites append some url params to image urls like “format=auto&width=720”.
How does that work? Do they store images in different sizes and fetch them based on screen width? Or is it somehow formatted on the frontend?
Or maybe they have endpoints that fetch and resize images and then show them?

I am using nodejs and ejs for templating if anyone can help me achieve that with them?

Answer (score 0):

These websites literally resize the stored original in RAM, serverside, then deliver it.

If there's caching in front of this, it might actually be quite cheap, because each resize happens once (until cache invalidates). Those resizes commonly happen for the benefit of, and by the request of, content management systems.